# Is there a shorter way in ruby to get the later of two dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

just curious - is there a shorter way to achieve this?

```
latest_date = date1 > date2 ? date1 : date2
```

thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#max`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max):

```
latest_date = [date1, date2].max
```

Comment: Say, date1 is optional (can be nil), use [date1 || date2, date2].max For what it's worth :)

Comment: @caya In that case you probably want `[date1, date2].compact.max`

Comment: @NiklasB. what is the purpose of adding `.compact`? Never mind, I looked it up (as I should of to begin with). Compact will take out the nil values.

Answer (score 4):

Try `latest_date = [date1, date2].max`. I just ran that in my IRB and got the later of the two dates.